# Tab always selected in TabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I have a problem with my TabHost, inside a Fragment, the first tab to be selected will always be highlighted, so I have often two tabs selected as shown here

[image: first image, notifications tabs is highlighted when it should not]

**Here Notifications should not be highlighted !**

But the problem is only for Notifications tab, as you can see here the tab friends behave just normally, because it is the second added..

[image: Secend picture here, friends works normally]

Here is my code for the fragment holding my TabHost

```
public class ProfileContentFragment extends Fragment {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
public ProfileContentFragment() {
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_content_fragment,container, false);


    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)     rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getFragmentManager(),      android.R.id.tabcontent);

              mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("notifications").setIndicator("Notifications    "),
            NotificationsFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("friends").setIndicator("Friends"),
            FriendsFragment.class, null);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();;
    mTabHost=null;
}
}
```

And here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you solved your own question please post an answer with the solution and accept it instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED :**

It was solved by changing

```
 mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getFragmentManager(),     android.R.id.tabcontent);
```

To :

`mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),       android.R.id.tabcontent);`